# Spring simple websocket project returns 200 code

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

I build simple websocket project (located at localhost:4000)

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
        http
                .cors().and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll() // Permit ws connection
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));

       // cors config below
```

After that trying to connect from client, located at localhost:3000.
And got 200 status instead of 101.

```
import { Stomp, Client } from '@stomp/stompjs';

  let client = new Client({
    brokerURL: "ws://localhost:4000/ws"
  })

  client.activate()
```

Server replied with header `Connection: keep-alive` instead of `Connection: Update` and returns 200 status

Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In WebSocketConfig.java, you have configured the endpoint as /ws -

```
registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .withSockJS();
```

While making connection to the websocket endpoint from the typescript front-end do this -

```
let ws = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws") ;  // localhost:8080 can be your backend endpoint
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
```

When using sockjs library, we have to connect over the http protocol and then internally the library manages the WS connection.

Comment: And your question?